# Inclusion induces identity on homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $(H_*, \partial_*)$ be a homology theory with values in the category of $\Bbb{Z}$-modules satisfying the dimension axiom. Then the inclusion $S^1\vee S^1\to T^2$ should induce (up to isomorphism) the identity on $\Bbb{Z}\oplus \Bbb{Z}\cong H_1(S^1\vee S^1) \to H_1(T^2)\cong \Bbb{Z}\oplus \Bbb{Z}$ but I haven't been able to prove it.

I've tried using LES of the pair $(T^2, S^1\vee S^1)$ with no success. Note that this is in the setting of a general homology theory, and we may not use geometric considerations from singular homology.

Comment: $H_1(S^1)$ need not be $\mathbb{Z}$ in an arbitrary ordinary homology theory. In fact, there's only one in which it is.

Comment: He wrote "satisfying the dimension axiom". So $H_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is true.

Comment: @archipelago $H_*(-; \mathbb{Q})$ satisfies the dimension axiom, but $H_1(S^1; \mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q} \not\cong \mathbb{Z}$. The dimension axiom says $H_n(\mathrm{pt}) = 0 \; \forall n \neq 0$, nothing else.

Comment: I see. I supposed he was assuming a homology theory with values in abelian groups.

Comment: @archipelago But $H_*(-; \mathbb{Q})$ *is* valued in abelian groups. $\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian group.

Comment: I am indeed assuming that the homology theories takes values in the category of $\Bbb{Z}$-modules. I should have of course mentioned that in my question ( I edited it now )

Comment: @Najib Idrissi By the dimension axiom for a "homology theory valued in abelian groups" I mean that the point should have trivial homology except in degree 0, where it should be isomorphic to the integers. You're right, there is only one theory (at least for finite CW-complexes) which fulfills this, but I expected that the point of the question was to conclude the claim just from the axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working with homology with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$, the long exact sequence of $(X, A) = (T^2, S^1 \vee S^1)$ works just fine :

$$\cdots \to H_2(A) \to H_1(X) \to H_2(X, A) \stackrel{\partial}{\to} H_1(A) \to H_1(X) \to H_1(X, A) \to \cdots$$

As $H_2(A) = 0$, and $H_1(X, A) \cong H_1(X/A, \text{pt}) = H_1(S^2, \text{pt}) = 0$, this reduces to the exact sequence

$$0 \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z \stackrel{\partial}{\to} \Bbb Z^2 \to \Bbb Z^2 \to 0$$

The second homomorphism has to be multiplication by some integer $n$. In that case, image has to be $n\Bbb Z$, which is in turn equal to kernel of $\partial$ by exactness. Thus, by first isomorphism theorem, $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ has to be a subgroup of $\Bbb Z^2$, which is possible if and only if $n$ is either $0$ or $1$, and the former is impossible as then the second map in the sequence would be zero, forcing $\Bbb Z \cong 0$.

Hence, the second map is an isomorphism, implying $\partial$ is the zero map. Thus, the fourth map $\Bbb Z^2 \to \Bbb Z^2$ has kernel $0$, and is thus injective. It's also surjective as the fifth map is zero, hence is an isomorphism.

Comment: $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z^2$ if $n = 0$ too. But this would imply $\mathbb Z = 0$ by the first part of the sequence.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Corrected, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Show that $S^1\amalg S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^1$ is an iso on $H_1$ and $S^1\amalg S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^1\hookrightarrow T^2$ as well. Fixing an iso $H_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ , the map $H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\rightarrow H_1(T^2)$ is represented by the identity relative to the  induced isos $H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\cong H_1(T^2)$.

Comment: I only managed to prove the first assertion that $S^1\amalg S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^1$ induces an iso on $H_1$. What method did you have in mind to prove the other assertion?

Comment: The first possibility, which comes to my mind is the following: Write $T^2$ as a pushout of $S^1\vee S^1$ and use the LES of the pair $(T^2,S^1\vee S^1)$ to conclude that $H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\rightarrow H_1(T^2)$ is an iso. The relative homology of $(T^2,S^1\vee S^1)$ is the one of $(D^2,S^1)$ by a Mayer-Vietoris argument, which you can derive just from the axioms.